# set MAC address in "interfaces" file without configuring other network parameters

Tags: linux, debian, ethernet, mac-address

Under Debian Wheezy permanent network configuration takes place in `/etc/network/interfaces` file. Is it possible to configure `hwaddress` for an interface without configuring other network parameters like `address` or `netmask`? Something like:

```
root@1:~# cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0
hwaddress ether DE:AD:BE:EF:69:01

# The primary network interface
auto eth0.100
iface eth0.100 inet static
        address 10.1.1.2
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 10.1.1.0
        broadcast 10.1.1.255
        gateway 10.1.7.1
root@1:~#
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for `iface eth0 inet manual`. This allows configuration like:

```
root@1:~# cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
        hwaddress ether DE:AD:BE:EF:69:01

# The primary network interface
auto eth0.100
iface eth0.100 inet static
        address 10.1.1.2
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 10.1.1.0
        broadcast 10.1.1.255
        gateway 10.1.7.1
root@1:~#
```